# Saving list with AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

So I made a "notepad" app and I want to do so the text that the user wrote etc it should be saved, so the text doesn't get reset when user quits the app.

I'm new to react-native, after a few google searches I need AsyncStorage? to make this happen.
but really dunno on how to do it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { 
StyleSheet, 
Text, 
View, 
FlatList, 
TouchableWithoutFeedback, 
TouchableOpacity,
Keyboard,
AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
import Header from './components/header';
import ListItem from './components/listitem';
import AddList from './components/addlist';

export default function App() {

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([

    ]);

    const pressHandler = (key) => {
      setTodos((prevTodos) => {
      return prevTodos.filter(todo => todo.key != key);
     });
    }

    const submitHandler = (text) => {
      if(text.length > 0) {
        setTodos((prevTodos) => {
        return [
       { text: text, key: Math.random().toString() },
      ...prevTodos
     ];
   })
   } 
  }

 return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
   }}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Header />
     <View style={styles.content}>
      <AddList  submitHandler={submitHandler} />
       <View style={styles.todoList}>
        <FlatList 
          data={todos}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem item={item} pressHandler={pressHandler} />
           )}
        />
      </View>
     </View>
   </View>
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
  }
```

new problem out of nowhere worked great before now broken without touching the code

```
    const pressHandler = key =>
      setTodos(prevTodos => {
       const newTodos = prevTodos.filter(todo => todo.key !== key);

      storeTodosInAsync(newTodos);

      console.log(prevTodos);
    return newTodos;

    });


const submitHandler = text => {
  if (text.length > 0) {
      const key = Math.random().toString();
        setTodos(prevTodos => {
        const newTodos = [{ text, key }, ...prevTodos];

        storeTodosInAsync(newTodos);
        console.log(newTodos);
        return newTodos;
     });
   }
 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AsyncStorage to store and load data to/from local storage. One thing to note is data MUST be a string, so anything like an object that is not a string needs to be stringified. You can use `JSON.stringify(...)` to do this. And then when you get the string back you can use `JSON.parse(...)` to convert it back into an object.

So to convert your current code into something that automatically loads saved todos and always saves the latest, you could write this:

```js
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      FlatList,
      TouchableWithoutFeedback,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Keyboard,
      AsyncStorage,
      Button
    } from 'react-native';
    import Header from './components/header';
    import ListItem from './components/listitem';
    import AddList from './components/addlist';
    
    export default function App() {
      const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        restoreTodosFromAsync();
      }, []);
    
      const pressHandler = key => {
        console.log('Todos BEFORE delete');
        console.log(todos);
    
        const newTodos = todos.filter(todo => todo.key !== key);
    
        console.log('Todos AFTER delete');
        console.log(todos);
    
        setTodos(newTodos);
        storeTodosInAsync(newTodos);
      };
    
      const submitHandler = text => {
        if (text.length === 0) return;
    
        const key = Math.random().toString();
    
        console.log('Todos BEFORE submit');
        console.log(todos);
    
        const newTodos = [{ text, key }, ...todos];
    
        console.log('Todos AFTER submit');
        console.log(todos);
    
        setTodos(newTodos);
        storeTodosInAsync(newTodos);
      };
    
      const asyncStorageKey = '@todos';
    
      const storeTodosInAsync = newTodos => {
        const stringifiedTodos = JSON.stringify(newTodos);
    
        AsyncStorage.setItem(asyncStorageKey, stringifiedTodos).catch(err => {
          console.warn('Error storing todos in Async');
          console.warn(err);
        });
      };
    
      const restoreTodosFromAsync = () => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem(asyncStorageKey)
          .then(stringifiedTodos => {
            console.log('Restored Todos:');
            console.log(stringifiedTodos);
    
            const parsedTodos = JSON.parse(stringifiedTodos);
    
            if (!parsedTodos || typeof parsedTodos !== 'object') return;
    
            setTodos(parsedTodos);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.warn('Error restoring todos from async');
            console.warn(err);
          });
      };
    
      return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header />
            <View style={styles.content}>
              <AddList submitHandler={submitHandler} />
              <View style={styles.todoList}>
                <FlatList
                  data={todos}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => <ListItem item={item} pressHandler={pressHandler} />}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      );
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but when i press save nothing saves nothing is there when i reload the app. if i press restore the notes come back. maybe this is cuz i have addlist.js and listitem.js that are then imported to app.js

Comment: by messing around in the app ive come up with that the save button work but only for the restore button when notes have been deleted.

Comment: now after a few days not working on the project the app doesn't work with asyncstorage it only works if i remove the code you added. i dunno how it worked the day i asked the question. no error in the code editior (vs studio) but on expo it throws error (invalid attempt to spread non-iterible instance) i havnt found a solution for this on google or stackoverflow thats why im asking here again. the code is the same as ur answer above.

Comment: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance. This error is located at: in App (at withExpoRoot.js:26) in RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:25) in ExpoRoot (atrenderApplication.js:40) in RCTView (at Appcontainer.js:101) in RCTView (at Appcontainer.js:119) in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)  i have zero qlues on what this evan means. oh and the app loads the ui but when i press add everything crashes and throws this error.

Comment: i didnt get anything out of console.log did i put console.log in the right place? look on the updated code above to see where i put the console.log

Comment: deleting the cache didnt work still the same issue. now with the console log and errors it says INFO
11:04
Restored Todos:
INFO
11:04
null
INFO
11:04
Todos BEFORE submit
INFO
11:04
null

Comment: it works now finally. thank you for putting ur time into this and helping me.